# How does NETCORE get the attribute values of custom properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributes

1.development environment：

- C#
- NetCore-2.1

2.First, I define the following characteristics

```
public class DynaimcInfo : System.Attribute
{
     public DynaimcInfo(int type, string module, string model)
     {
         this.Type = type;
         this.Module = module;
         this.Model = model;
     }
     public int Type { get; }
     public string Module { get; }
     public string Model { get; }
}
```

3.I used custom features in a certain class of methods.

```
[DynaimcInfo(1,"Test","No.1")]
public void Test()
{
    //How do I get the attribute values of custom attributes here?
}
```

4.My goal is to write a log uniformly when calling a method, and the parameters of the feature will determine the module information of the log writing.

```
[DynaimcInfo(1,"Test1","No.1")]
    public void Test1()
    {
        xx.log(1,"Test","No.1")
    }
 [DynaimcInfo(2,"Test2","No.2")]
    public void Test()
    {
        xx.log(2,"Test2","No.2")
    }
```

**Problem：How do I get the attribute values type, model and module in the custom method test ()?**

Comment: You wouldn't.  Attributes are statically compiled.  Therefore, all information you need about the attribute is present when you write the code.  So why create a weird attribute when you can just put that info in the code itself?  Attributes are designed to be used by framework code that doesn't know the details when the code is written

Comment: My goal is to get the parameters of writing log in the method. In order to write log, we need to know the module and attributes of the method, which belong to the method information. So I think it would be better to put this information into the features of the method. Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Again, since you have to put this code in your source code anyways, there is no real advantage to using an attribute here.  Attributes are typically used when you have some framework that calls your code.  For instance, when using Aspect Oriented Programming, or with MVC (where the framework examines the attributes and makes decisions based on them).  You could use an attribute to write to the log (using the parameters) but you still need something that will dispatch that function, and without a framework to do that it's pointless.

Comment: You might look at the PostSharp framework to implement what you want to do.  There's also an article here https://nearsoft.com/blog/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-net-core-and-c-using-autofac-and-dynamicproxy/

Comment: The point here, though.. is that .net core doesn't get any attribute properties other than the ones that it, itself supports.  Anything custom you would have to write custom reflection code to observe them and potentially act on them.  That's what those AOP frameworks do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the above solution

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get the values in normal code - as was previously mentioned in the comments. What you need is a way of proxying the call. CastleWindsor provides a library to do this, in a similar fashion to how Unit Tests are wrapped in most frameworks.

Additionally, I have a library that handles this case, available on Github: https://github.com/f135ta/SimpleProxy